# Alert Dialog builder doesn't have dismiss or cancel method

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I know that there are lot of solutions currently to this question, but i couldn't solve with any of them.
Actually i created a imageView and i set a listener to that imageView, i also created a custom builder to create my own alertDialog, what i need is to close the dialog when i click on the imageView so i did something like this:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Friends.this);
LayoutInflater inflater = Friends.this.getLayoutInflater();
                final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_builder, null);
close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    }
                });
 builder.show();
```

this is just part of my code, the builder.show is working fine, the close is the name of my imageView.

Thank you very much guys.

Comment: doesn't the alert dialog lay over the image view that closes it? you won't be able to close the dialog this way

Answer (score 2):

you have to add builder.create() method for dismiss dialog. get an instance and dismiss it.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Friends.this);
    AlertDialog dialogInstance=builder.create();
    LayoutInflater inflater = Friends.this.getLayoutInflater();
                    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_builder, null);
                        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialogInstance.dismiss()
                        }
                    });
     builder.show();
```

happy coding :)